# Кнопка fullscreen ролика youtube

Tags: jquery, youtube

Какая команда дублирует функцию кнопки fullscreen внутри youtube? Делаю кастомное управление, дизайном предусмотрена такая "сторонняя" кнопка. Сейчас вот такой код:

```
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('video-1', {
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
  });
  player2 = new YT.Player('video-2', {
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  var stopButton = $('.videotab--header label');
  stopButton.click(function() {
    player.stopVideo();
    player2.stopVideo();

  });

  var playButton = $('.play-video--button');
  playButton.click(function() {
    player2.playVideo();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//обработка нажатия на кастомную кнопку
$(playButtonClass).addEventListener('click', function(){
  // Воспроизвидим и потом развораричаваем на весь экран
  player.playVideo();

  var playerElement = $(playerWrapperClass);
  var requestFullScreen = playerElement.requestFullScreen || playerElement.mozRequestFullScreen || playerElement.webkitRequestFullScreen;
  if (requestFullScreen) {
    requestFullScreen.bind(playerElement)();
  }
})
```

Нашел такой вариант.

Беглый поиск по гуглу говорит что идея, сама по себе, так делать не входит в философию Youtube.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.button').click(function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("video");
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  }
});
```

но при это в теге iframe обязательно должны быть прописаны следующие моменты:

```
webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen
```